# What exact does MIB represent in SNMP? How is it different from OID?

Tags: snmp, management

In SNMP, we represent each entity of information using object and to identify each object uniquely, we use OID (Object Identifier).
Now there is another terminology - MIB. I know it stands for "Management Information Base". However, I am not able to understand the concept of the term MIB.

Below is the image which represents the pictorial representation of object hierarchy tree-

[image]

rttMonCtrlAdminTag, rttMonCtrlAdminRttType, rttMonCtrlAdminFrequency represents Objects and corresponding OIDs are

.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.42.1.2.1.1.3

.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.42.1.2.1.1.4

.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.42.1.2.1.1.6

In this pictorial representation what does MIB represent?

Comment: MIB is the whole collection of OIDs - usually with specific reference to a hardware/OS platform. the MIB for a router is different to that of a firewall and differs between vendors but each MIB is a collection of OIDs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The MIB is the entire catalog of OIDs (for a particular device).

An OID is a specific reference to an individual item within the MIB.

An analogy: The MIB is like the phone book for my city. The OID is like my name in the phone book.

Comment: a device will (usually) support a collection of MIBs, often partially.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that MIB is a certain amount of OIDs grouped by the single purpose.
Example:
Entity-MIB contains a lot of OIDs to display device physical structure.
IP-MIB is all about the IPs.
CISCO-CDP-MIB will give you info about connected neighbors to a port with cdp configured.
etc.